# Get dates based on a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
id       age
001      1 hour
002      2 hours
003      2 days
004      4 days
```

Age refers to how long the item has been in the database. What I like to do is to print the date when the item is being added to the database.

So if **age** column contains the string "hour" or "hours", I want to print the current date, and if not, deduct current date by the number of days.

The desired output should look like this:

```
id       age          insertion_date
001      1 hour       2018-09-18
002      2 hours      2018-09-18
003      2 days       2018-09-16
004      4 days       2018-09-14
```

I am using Python 2.7 and so far this is what I have achieved.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    age = row["age"]
    if "days" in age:
       # Remove days and convert data type of age column 
       df["age"] = df["age"].astype("str").str.replace('[^\d\.]', '')
       # deduct current date by number of days
       df["insertion_date"] = df["age"].astype("int64").apply(lambda x: date.today() - timedelta(x))
     else:
       # print current date
       df["insertion_date"] = date.today()
```

The output from the code above looks like this:

```
id       age          insertion_date
001      1            2018-09-17
002      2            2018-09-16
003      2            2018-09-16
004      4            2018-09-14
```

The issue with this code is that even when the string "hour" or "hours" is present in the **age** column, it does not add the current date into the **insertion_date** column.

Would appreciate if someone can point out where I went wrong with this code so I can fix it to get the desired output i.e. it will add current date to the **insertion_date** column if the string "hour" or "hours" is present in the **age** column, otherwise, deduct the current date to the number of days in the **age** column and add the date to the **insertion_date** column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) subtracted by `timedelta`s created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`TimedeltaIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.floor.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('D') - pd.to_timedelta(df['age']).dt.floor('D')
print (df)
   id      age        new
0   1   1 hour 2018-09-18
1   2  2 hours 2018-09-18
2   3   2 days 2018-09-16
3   4   4 days 2018-09-14

print (df['new'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a little timedeltarithmetic:

```
df['insertion_date'] = (
    pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_timedelta(df.age).dt.floor('D')).dt.date

df
   id      age insertion_date
0   1   1 hour     2018-09-18
1   2  2 hours     2018-09-18
2   3   2 days     2018-09-16
3   4   4 days     2018-09-14
```